# Bootstrap Table Page List Not Working,Why Hide The Page List Options?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I am using HTML like this

```
<table id="eventsTable" data-sortable="true" data-checkbox="true"
                    data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10,25,50,ALL]">

                   </table>
```

then i am using script like this

```
 $('#eventsTable').bootstrapTable({
                pagination: true,
                pageList: [10, 25, 50, ALL],
                pageSize:10,
```

but page List is not working,i don't know y its not working.anyone give some suggestion for me

Answer (score 0):

Please find below mentioned solution. You have to add quotes in ALL.

```
pageList: [10, 25, 50, 'ALL']
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Already apply. The page list not enable in table so not listed that options,